# How Do I Make my coin (a 2D sprite) destroy itself when the player (another 2D sprite) enters its trigger in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have them both on sorting layer 6 (On the sprite renderer)
I'm not too sure what I've done wrong.
here is what I have on my coin at the moment:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `score` a property of the gingerbread (and not a property of the game)? That aside, nothing appears to be wrong with setting that score value to a text object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of your score. What you are changing the value of is a *copy* of your game's score, but not the actual score.

```cs
float gingerscore = Gamemanager.score; //Creates a new float, with the same value as Gamemanager.score
gingerscore--;//Decrease the newly created float's value by one, but not the original object.
```

What you need to do is either reassign `gingerscore` to `Gamemanager.score`. Or edit the `Gamemanager.score` value directly like this:

```cs
//This method is a bit roundabout, but will work and is closest to what you try currently
float gingerscore = Gamemanager.score; //Make a copy of score
gingerscore--;//Decrement the value
Gamemanager.score = gingerscore; //Assign the new value back to score

//This is a more straightforward approach to doing the same thing
Gamemanager.score--;//Decrement the score directly
```

You may want to read up on the difference between copying data by value or by reference in C#. Jon Skeet has a good article [on it here](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html).

(On a side note for better readability in your code. Start new words with a capital letter. E.g `gingerScore` and `GameManager`. Naming conventions for C# can be [found here](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md))

Comment: Is your gingerbread's world position actually falling below -4.9y? Or is its local position falling below -4.9? There is a big difference between the two. Try using `gameObject.transform.localPosition.y < -4.9f`

Comment: Can you add the code you are using the make your gingerbread fall to your original question? The problem may be in there.